# How to run the configuration Wizard? From GUI or command line?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, configuration-wizard, patching

What is the best practice to run the configuration wizard post patching? Was it from GUI or command line?

From Command line i regularly see the below command

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

but from the post [NOV CU 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2017/12/05/after-updating-sharepoint-2013-to-november-2017-cu-or-later-you-may-not-be-able-to-open-documents-with-office/) the best way is to run using below command

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install
```

What the meaning of each parameter?

Answer (score 3):

The answer for the first question really differs if you ask different SharePoint-Guys. **I** prefer psconfig.exe, where over my colleague prefers the Products Configuration Wizard (psconfigui.exe).

[Stefan Goßner also prefers psconfigui.exe](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/08/20/why-i-prefer-psconfigui-exe-over-psconfig-exe/) and also explains why.

[A detailled description on every parameter can be found on Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093(v=office.14).aspx). It's for 2010, but still applies for 2013 & 2016.

My practical experience when patching SharePoint systems:

- I first run `psconfig.exe` with Stefan Goßner's parameters. This regularly fails. I directly run `psconfig.exe`again with same parameters. No troubleshooting or even a look at the error-log here!
- If update still fails, i run `psconfigui.exe`. If this still failes, i run `psconfigui.exe`again.
- If all of this failes, you really need to troubleshoot this issue. But you will get 95% of your issues resolved just with this weird procedure.
- If you prefer `psconfigui.exe` over `psconfig.exe`, you can simple change the first steps. Begin with UI, then change to CLI if no success.

Comment: To counter, I prefer psconfigui.exe. You can't mess that up :-)

Comment: Best pro argument for UI i've ever seen. This could change my default recommendation for customers. :-) Thanks!

Comment: "Use this one easy trick to configure SharePoint servers!" ;)